# find exact matches in text

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with reviews. I want to search for exact strings in this text.

For example a piece of this dataset:

*this dentist is great

this dentist is great, however, his assistant is bad

perfect

I don't like my dentist, he is not perfect*

When the strings "perfect" and "this dentist is great" occur in the dataset, they must be returned in the new dataset. But only if it matches exactly. So only lines 1 and 3 should return in the dataset.

My script returns all the lines:

```
df_return=df[df["columnA"].str.contains("perfect|this dentist is great")==True]
df_return
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your script.

Comment: use regex and condition in str.contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, replace it with

```
df_return=df[df["columnA"].str.contains("^perfect$|^this dentist is great$")==True]
```

Output:

```
                 columnA
0  this dentist is great
2                perfect
```

Answer (score 1):

Use straight equal check == instead of contains something like

```
if df["columnA"].str == 'perfect' or df["columnA"].str == 'this dentist is great':
    print(["columnA"].str)
```

or

```
if df["columnA"].str in {'perfect', 'this dentist is great'}:
    print(["columnA"].str)
```

Comment: When I run your script I get an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @marita exact implementation depends on the source code, which is missing in initial message. I've updated my solution a little bit, so you can give one more try. But try to adapt my advice to you implementation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `match` to check for the same

```
df_return = df[df['columnA'].str.match(pat='(perfect)|(this dentist is great)')]
df_return
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work -

```
df_return = df[df['columnA'].str.contains('perfect') | df['columnA'].str.contains('this dentist is perfect')]
```